# How to move multiple files to multiple folders in linux?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, mv

I have a folder containing `*.fastq.gz` files (R1 and R2) for many samples. For example, in the folder "Raw_WGS", I have several files like

```
Sample_1_R1.fastq.gz, Sample_1_R2.fastq.gz, Sample_2_R1.fastq.gz, Sample_2_R2.fastq.gz, Sample_3_R1.fastq.gz, Sample_3_R2.fastq.gz
```

I have another folder e.g. "Analysis" where I have different sub-folders according to the name of my sample sequences. I have sub-folders named like

```
Sample_1, Sample_2, Sample_3
```

I have a Text file containing all and ONLY the names of my samples i.e. `Sample_1, Sample_2, Sample_3`. Now, I want to move the `*_R1.fastq.gz` and `*_R2.fastq.gz` files for each sample to their respective sub-folder according to the name in the "Analysis" folder.

Can you please tell me how can I do that for all the samples at once? I can use the `mv` command to move each file at a time. But I have 1000s of files. So, I want to move them all by running a single script. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Loop across the directory names, and move matching files

Comment: This might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527073/move-files-to-specific-folders-based-on-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need a file with the names, since *they are already in the file names*. Try  this:

```bsh
for i in *_R{1,2}.fastq.gz; do 
  # use `cp` to be sure it works
  cp "$i" /path/toAnalisys/"${i%_*}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Samples.txt contains Sample_1 till 3 one per lne , we can setup an xargs command to call mv

```
tree -F
< Samples.txt \
xargs -I {} -t mv -t Analysis/{}/ \
       Raw_WGS/{}_R1.fastq.gz  \
       Raw_WGS/{}_R2.fastq.gz ;
tree -F
```

**Results:**

```
Before move...
 .
├── Analysis/
│   ├── Sample_1/
│   ├── Sample_2/
│   ├── Sample_3/
│   ├── Sample_4/
│   └── Sample_5/
└── Raw_WGS/
    ├── Sample_1_R1.fastq.gz
    ├── Sample_1_R2.fastq.gz
    ├── Sample_2_R1.fastq.gz
    ├── Sample_2_R2.fastq.gz
    ├── Sample_3_R1.fastq.gz
    └── Sample_3_R2.fastq.gz

After move...
.
├── Analysis/
│   ├── Sample_1/
│   │   ├── Sample_1_R1.fastq.gz
│   │   └── Sample_1_R2.fastq.gz
│   ├── Sample_2/
│   │   ├── Sample_2_R1.fastq.gz
│   │   └── Sample_2_R2.fastq.gz
│   ├── Sample_3/
│   │   ├── Sample_3_R1.fastq.gz
│   │   └── Sample_3_R2.fastq.gz
│   ├── Sample_4/
│   └── Sample_5/
└── Raw_WGS/
```